# External Hysteresis Resistive Divider for MAX 6777

Tags: voltage-divider

I want to switch on power to an ESP32, when a capacitor reaches 4.8V, and turn off the power, when 3.3V are reached.
In this question:
[Use supercapacitor to power microcontroller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/687079/use-supercapacitor-to-power-microcontroller)
I was asked to better use a MAX677x IC, so I bought an MAX6777. In order to set the hysteresis voltage, I have to calculate 3 resistor values. Here's the datasheet:
https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/download/137262/MAXIM/MAX6777XKT.html
See page 8 "Calculating an External Hysteresis Resistive Divider".
I calculated:

```
Battery monitor
GND
.|
RL
.+------LBH-o+--+o-BATT
RHYST   GND-o|  |
.+------LBL-u+--+o-LBO
RH
.|
VBATT
See figure 3: Single-Channel Adjustable-Hysteresis Block Diagram
e_A=                                                                     = 0.005
                                                                 Allowable error

V_BATT_RISING=                                                          = 4.8[V]
                                                        desired rising threshold

V_BATT_FALLING=                                                         = 3.3[V]
                                                       desired falling threshold

I_L=                                                                  = 5e-09[A]
                                                worst-case leakage current (5nA)

V_LBI=                                                                 = 1.22[V]

      e_A*V_BATT_RISING
R_H = -----------------
             I_L       
R_H=                                                                 = 4.8e06[Ω]

             V_LBI*R_H       
R_LO = ----------------------
       (V_BATT_FALLING-V_LBI)
R_LO=                                                               = 2.82e06[Ω]

      V_LBI*(R_H+R_LO)
R_L = ----------------
       V_BATT_RISING  
R_L=                                                                = 1.94e06[Ω]

R_HYST = R_LO-R_L
R_HYST=                                                            = 882.1e03[Ω]
```

The resistor values are very high I think. Did I make some misstake, or is it really MegaOhms, I have to use?

Comment: High resistor values are very common in this context. I didn't verify the calulation, but it sounds plausible.